# Vue 3, Composition API: the "Exclude" TypeScript utility type causes a prop validation error

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-props

I'm using Vue 3 with the Composition API and TypeScript, everything at its latest stable version.

Suppose I have the following types:

```
export interface Person {
    name: string;
}

export type Status = Person | 'UNLOADED' | null;
```

Now I want to use `Status` as a prop in a component, but removing the `null` possibility – because a validation is already made in the parent component, so validating the `null` again is redundant.

In order to do so, we need the [`Exclude`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludeuniontype-excludedmembers) utility type:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
const props = defineProps<{
    status: Exclude<Status, null>;
}>();
</script>
```

When I do this, all validations inside the component work 100% correct.

However, when I run the application and `'UNLOADED'` is passed as the prop value, I receive the following warning:

```
[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "status".
Expected Object, got String with value "UNLOADED".
```

Then I decided to translate it to the Options API. And, to my surprise, this declaration worked perfectly:

```
<script lang="ts">
import {defineComponent, PropType} from 'vue';

export default defineComponent({
    props: {
        status: {
            type: [Object, String] as PropType<Exclude<Status, null>>,
            required: true,
        },
    },
});
</script>
```

So it seems that, in Composition API, Vue considers that `Exclude` **always** returns an object, and since a string is not an object, it complains about the (inexistent) prop validation error.

Is this some sort of bug?

How can I work around it with the Composition API?

Answer (score 1):

This syntax becomes valid in Vue 3.3+

```js
export interface Person {
    name: string
}
export type Status = Person | "UNLOADED" | null
const props = defineProps<{
    status: Exclude<Status, null>
}>()
```

**< Vue 3.3**

In the composition API you should declare the props in this way :

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
import { PropType} from 'vue';

const props = defineProps({
    status: {
            type: [Object, String] as PropType<Exclude<Status, null>>,
            required: true,
        }
});
</script>
```

The syntax `defineProps<SomeType>()` supports only :

- A type literal
- A reference to an interface or a type literal in the same file

Currently complex types and type imports from other files are not supported. It is possible to support type imports in the future.